# How to check if condoms are good to use?

Tags: contraception, expiration-dates, condom

Is there a way to test if a condoms is good to use? Say you have a bag of 100, and you want to test couple of them to make sure the rest are still good. Assuming we are going to dispose of the test condoms.

Answer (score 2):

Fill them with water. If they leak, they're bad. Just keep in mind they're not meant to withstand pressure, so don't fill them to bursting. Use just enough water to show if there are any leaks.